# Map a file in Docker using Docker Volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I've created a WAR file and running it as an Image using Tomcat in Docker

So in the WAR file contain a Java Web App

I got a config.properties file in the WAR.

I want to be able to modify the config.properties file when the container is running and map the modified file in Docker Volume for storage

Comment: Does this issue solve your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177238/change-a-config-properties-file-in-a-jar-war-file-in-runtime-and-hotdeploy-the

Comment: Not really everything is related to docker not with the WAR file

Comment: A war is an archive. Changing something in a war is always the same thing, be it on docker or a simple host (and it's not a good idea). But if you really struggle with docker, you should look at bind mounts/volumes and put your war in one. But I don't think it's the way to go, the question I linked seems the better way.